# How can I embed an image in XML?

Tags: html, css, xml, dtd

I want to open the XML file with my browser and have the data displayed along with a logo image, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I have searched A LOT but cannot find a simple explanation, even though I am sure it is probably very simple. I have three files: the XML file, a DTD file and a CSS file. All the data is displayed correctly except for the image, which as far as I can tell, I have included the code for correctly in the XML and DTD files (maybe I need to add something to the CSS file to make it appear?).

Here is my (condensed) code for the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="CarAcc_13007620.css"?>
<!-- This document contains data on the Car Accessories Shop -->
<!DOCTYPE shop SYSTEM "CarAcc_13007620.dtd"
[
<!ENTITY shoplogo SYSTEM "shoplogo.jpg" NDATA JPG>
]
>

<shop>
<shopname>Car Accessories</shopname>
<address>330 Goswell Road, London, EC1V 7LQ</address>
<telnumber>078502982</telnumber>
<website>https://www.caraccessories123.co.uk</website>
<logo source="shoplogo"/>

<products>

<batterycharger manufacturer="BestBatteries Ltd">
<name>Basic Battery Charger</name>
<itemnumber>P0001</itemnumber>
<description>This basic battery charger will charge batteries quickly and 
efficiently and is great value for money!</description>
<quantity>5</quantity>
<price>&#163; 7.50</price>
</batterycharger>

</products>

</shop>
```

Here is my DTD file:

```
<!ELEMENT shop (shopname, address, telnumber, website, logo, products)>
<!ELEMENT shopname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT address (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT telnumber (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT website (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT logo EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST logo source ENTITY #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT products (batterycharger+, seatcover+, carheater+, cupholder+, 
seatorganiser+, bootorganiser+)>

<!ELEMENT batterycharger (name, itemnumber, description, quantity, price)>
<!ATTLIST batterycharger manufacturer CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT seatcover (name, itemnumber, description, quantity, price, color)>
<!ATTLIST seatcover manufacturer CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT carheater (name, itemnumber, description, quantity, price)>
<!ATTLIST carheater manufacturer CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT cupholder (name, itemnumber, description, quantity, price)>
<!ATTLIST cupholder manufacturer CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT seatorganiser (name, itemnumber, description, quantity, price, 
material, color, foldable)>
<!ATTLIST seatorganiser manufacturer CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST seatorganiser tabletholder (Yes | No) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST seatorganiser delivery (Free | Express) #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT bootorganiser (name, itemnumber, description, quantity, price, 
material, color, foldable)>
<!ATTLIST bootorganiser manufacturer CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST bootorganiser delivery (Free | Express) #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT itemnumber (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT quantity (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT material (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT color (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT foldable (#PCDATA)>

<!NOTATION JPG SYSTEM "image/jpg">
```

When I launch the XML file with any browser, it all loads correctly except that no image is shown. Any ideas why? All the files including the image are in the same folder. The CSS file is basic and just aligns the text and so on, but I have not included any code in the CSS file for images, as I am not sure how to for this case or whether it should even be needed to simply display the image in the first place. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.